# Substituting K2CO3 for KOH in Soap

Tags: aqueous-solution, ph, soap

Wood water obtained by running water through hardwood ashes has a high quantity of $\ce{K2CO3}$, historicaly this was called lye.  Yet soap recipes today seem to use $\ce{KOH}$ or $\ce{NaOH}$ as lye.

$\ce{KOH}$ is stronger than $\ce{K2CO3}$, so how would someone determine how much more $\ce{K2CO3}$ to substitute when $\ce{KOH}$ is called for in a recipe

I am using the method in the link to make lye, and the lye produced is mainly a combination of $\ce{K2CO3}$ and a little $\ce{Na2CO3}$, this should be sufficient to create soap

https://www.wikihow.com/Make-Lye

Comment: Hi, welcome to Chemistry.SE! Please note that you can render the chemical formulae with MathJax, using `$\ce{...}$`

Comment: $\ce{K2CO3}$ is not strong enough to make soap with oils, whatever its amount or concentration. And don't forget that ashes contains only $10 - 20$% $\ce{K2CO3}$. The main constituant of wood ashes is $\ce{CaCO3}$ which is present at $40 - 70$% . There is also $10 - 15$% $\ce{SiO2}$ and $5 - 10$% $\ce{MgCO3}$ in wood ashes

Comment: Historically, K2CO3 was not called lye, but potash . As lye was referred KOH, today mostly NaOH, both historically produced by process called caustification. ( $\ce{K2CO3 + Ca(OH)2 -> CaCO3 + 2 KOH}$ )

Comment: well then how come in both https://www.motherearthnews.com/homesteading-and-livestock/how-to-make-soap-from-ashes-zmaz72jfzfre and https://www.wikihow.com/Make-Lye it is referred to as lye

Comment: Chemists are a little picky about chemical names, including common language imprecise names such as “lye”. But your question has not been answered yet, so someone with soap making experience may yet answer.

Comment: There are sometimes differences what substances are called lye versus what solutions are called lye. That can be source of big confusion. The relative "strength" is not fixed number, it is concentration dependent. Generally, KOH is used in such amounts/concentration K2CO3 cannot replace it for the same effect. Count with saponification taking long time, unless you prepare "caustic potash" from "potash".